# Trying to add CSS file to HTML but getting 404 error

Tags: html, css

Here is my folder hierarchy:

```
/flask_app_2
    run.py
    /main
    __init__.py
    /static
        /js
        /styles
            styles.css
    /templates
        html_page.html
```

I am trying to add `styles.css` to my html_page but I keep getting a `404` error.

`<link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href="/static/style/style.css">`

Am I loading it correctly? Or do I possibly have a typo in my CSS file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing an "s" from your path.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href="/static/style/style.css">
```

Should be

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href="/static/styles/style.css">
```

so "/static/style***S***/style.css" instead of "/static/style/style.css".

Comment: ahh that was it. Thank you! Good eye.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you forget an "s" on styles
try this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href="/static/styles/styles.css">
```